# search with related_name Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have such models:

```
class LifeGoals(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Interests(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Sports(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    life_goals = models.ManyToManyField(LifeGoals, related_name='user_life_goals')
        # may be more than 1 choice
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Interests, related_name='user_interests')
        # may be more than 1 choice
    sports = models.ManyToManyField(Sports, related_name='user_sports')
        # may be more than 1 choice
```

How to write search filter with DjangoORM for such query (for example):

```
 User that has some options in LifeGoals and some options in Interests and some options in Sports
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try this:

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(life_goals__name="goal_name",
                           interests__name="interests_name", 
                           sports__name="sports_name")
```

But everything is well explained here : [django doc on queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: Tried to do that, but there is an error: Cannot resolve keyword 'user_life_goals' into field. Choices are:...

Comment: That's because the field is just 'life_goals' related_name refers to the reverse lookup.

Answer (score 2):

To specify a field that's in a related model you need to use double underscores

so `life_goals_name`  should be `life_goals__name`

There's your problem :)